# how to connect to database in drupal in order to display the content in a table

Tags: 8, database

I am using drupal in order to create a website on my localhost machine.

I have a mysql database that i want to connect it  to the drupal website and display its data in a table.

and in the drupal I download the [Views Database Connector (VDC)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) module in order to  connect to the external database.

but it did not work .

second method  I used views and created content types that are the fields table of the  external databases.

but I do not know how to continue to display the data.

third method  I created the tables in drupal database and want to display  its content .

I am new to drupal so I want  any of these method to  work for me

**note**  feeds module  also did not work because its not set up yet on the drupal 8.x

Comment: Maybe you want to give [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) a try also ... it has a DEV version for D8. If your question was about D7, you'd have a perfect solution (also as per your "I am new to Drupal" ...)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens so if i use the D7 i will find more solutions to my questions?? can i downgrade drupal version without having issues?

Comment: Maturity for contributed D7 modules is about 5 years ahead of D8 equivalents, so pretty sure you'll find many more solutions. In that case the module I recommended (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) is a perfect fit for what you're looking for. **But**: to downgrade from D8 to D7 is an extremely interesting challenge (which I have never encountered before). So starting from scratch might be your only alternative (possibly combined with import/export of content created already in D8).

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens i start from scratch with drupal 7 so now what is the best way to import data from external database or create a table within the drupal database or import csv file using feeds  ? although i will use these retrieved  data   in future to connected for example to google map or to an image.

Comment: Your question here is about D8 (so I cannot post a D7 answer to it ...). Maybe you want to look at my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/39983/39516)

Comment: i opened another thread can you take a look   (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226987/how-to-display-retrieved-data-from-a-table-in-the-drupal-database)

Answer (score 2):

You need add the followings lines in settings.php for connecting 'external' database.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
      'database' => 'drupal8',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'prefix' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '3306',
      'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
    );

$databases['external']['default'] = array(
  'database' => 'external',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

To activate external database

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('external');
```

//code to fetch data and display

To activate drupal database

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
```

If you are looking some example refer [How to connect to another database in your Drupal 8 site ?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2710557)

Comment: what about if i have the tables inside the drupal database how to display its content and where the php file exist in order to write the required code ...not the settings.php

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Clive i  have an excel file that i need to display its content on the website like a table so what i did i converted to csv  file in order to use feeds to import it but this method did not work. so i imported the file to the drupal database and create  4 content  types as they are the fields of the table  .... after that i did not know how to show the content of this database

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni, if you've imported the data to your drupal database you need to define the data structure of the table in `hook_views_data` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.2.x and then it will be visible in views. - Not to be confused with content types. Here you need to import the csv data directly with migrate (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_csv) or feeds when this is ready for D8.